# Should null be checked on the left or right hand side

Tags: c#, null, coding-style

In reviewing some code, I have seen:

```
if (null == condition) { ... }
```

and I've also seen:

```
if (condition == null) { ... }
```

I seem to remember that there's an advantage to having `null` on the left hand side, but I can't remember it and was thinking that it's an older runtime item that's been optimized away with newer .NET runtimes.  I tend to use the latter null check, so the former one catches my eye.

So is this a matter of style, or is there an advantage to having `null` be on the left or right hand side of an evaluation?

Comment: It was a hack in old C versions relevant before compilers started generating warnings about it.  Not a problem in C#, it has a *bool* type unlike C so it will yell at you when you write if (obj = null) {}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can make a difference in three cases.

One is where the typo of `condition = null` is valid in an `if`. This is more common in C-style languages that would allow `null` in an `if` (valued as `false`), which is most of them, but not C#.

It is possible to create a type that has this effect in C#:

```
public class Test
{
  public static bool operator true(Test x)
  {
    return true;
  }
  public static bool operator false(Test x)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
void Main()
{
  Test test = new test();
  if (test = null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("!");
  }
}
```

There's not a lot of times that overloading these operators make sense, especially since .Net 2.0 introduced generics (it had more value for types like `SqlBoolean` that enabled a value to indicate `true`, `false` or `null` in the way we'd now use `bool?`).

So this case is pretty marginal in C#.

Another is similar, if there's an implicit conversion to `bool` or to a type that in turn implements the `true` and `false` operators:

```
void Main()
{
  Test test = new Test();
  if (test = null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("!");
  }
}
public class Test
{
  public static implicit operator bool(Test x)
  {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Implicit operators are worth avoiding for a few reasons, but this is slightly more likely than the first example, though still nowhere near to being common.

Yet another is if `==` is overloaded in a non-symmetric manner:

```
public class Test
{
  public static bool operator == (Test x, Test y)
  {
    return ReferenceEquals(x, null);
  }
  public static bool operator !=(Test x, Test y)
  {
    return !(x == y);
  }
}
void Main()
{
  Test test = new Test();
  if (test == null)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("This won't print.");
  }
  if (null == test)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("This will print.");
  }
}
```

But since a non-symmetric `==` is always a bug, then this depends upon a bug in the operator to have any effect. This probably happens slightly more often than the first case, but it should be fixed when it does, so it's of even less real concern.

So while it can have an effect in C# the cases are rare and mostly based on someone else having done something they shouldn't.

As such, its mainly a matter of style. People who put the `null` first tend to have picked it up from languages where it makes more of a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  +1

Answer (score 9):

The classic reason in C-style languages is to protect against mis-typing the equality `==` as assignment `=`. You can't assign to a constant - i.e. the following is illegal and hence the compiler will catch the bug:

```
if (false = condition) { ... }
```

whereas this is totally legal (but probably not what the author intended:

```
if (condition = false) { ... }
```

Note: This problem is limited in C# (compared to say vanilla C) as `if` statements require a bool (as noted in the comments below), so the only case this actually causes problems is if your type is a `bool`.

Comment: Note that in `C#` this is *usually* not a problem, unless dealing with a boolean variable - which you can't compare to `null` anyway (and `bool?` is not a valid type in an `if` statement).

Comment: That's not legal in C# because `if` requires a `bool` and `null` cannot be assigned to a `bool`.

Comment: @juharr it's legal C#, because we don't know the type of `condition` so it could be one that overloads the `true` and `false` operators.

Comment: @JonHanna My comment was when this answer had `if(condition = null)`.  Now if `condition` is a `bool` then `if(condition = false)` is absolutely legal, but if as you said it's a type that has an implicit conversion from `bool` then it would not be legal unless it also had an implicit conversion to `bool`.

Comment: @juharr my reply was also when the answer had `if(condition = null)` (though there was a banner to say the answer had been edited). I'd forgotten implicit conversion, but that also makes it valid in the absence of information that there is no such conversion. I was thinking of the `true` operator, which also makes it potentially valid. Either are enough for the code as given to have been valid, because the code as-given doesn't have the information about the type that could make it invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how `(null == condition)` compiles, using an *exemplary* value like `null` as the first (left) operand is counter-intuitive. Instead, the first operand should suggest what you intend to evaluate.